# Should .csproj files be added to .gitignore?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I'm wondering if adding `.csproj` files in the git history is really useful / best / bad practice

(Currently, I'm using git for private repositories)

Thanks!

Comment: You could easily determine this.  Simply exit Visual Studio, delete your **.csproj** files, re-open your solution into Visual Studio and see what happens.  Of course be sure to back-up such files beforehand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:** You definitely need `.csproj` files in your `git` history.

**Long answer:** Here's how to answer a question like that.  Make a copy of your solution folder. Delete any files you wonder if they should be included in the `git` history.  Try to build and run your code.  If you can't, that means they are needed in `git`, and vice-versa.

In this case, you would discover that your project will not build without the `.csproj` file, hence that file must be in `git`.

It's also important to *remove* from `git` files that are not needed to build and run the project, such as files that are generated as part of the build process.

For the most part, this work has been done for you already, for example https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/.gitignore has a list of directories and extensions that should be ignored for `.Net Core` projects.  Other platforms/languages have similar `.gitignore` files posted.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400320/304683), it helps to know *what* project files are:

> When you create and build solutions in Visual Studio, Visual Studio uses MSBuild to build each project in your solution. Every Visual Studio project includes an MSBuild project file, with a file extension that reflects the type of project—for example, a C# project (.csproj), a Visual Basic.NET project (.vbproj), or a database project (.dbproj). In order to build a project, MSBuild must process the project file associated with the project. The project file is an XML document that contains all the information and instructions that MSBuild needs in order to build your project, like the content to include, the platform requirements, versioning information, web server or database server settings, and the tasks that must be performed.

- Ref to more details (`.Net`): [Understanding the project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file#the-anatomy-of-a-project-file)
- Similarly for `.Net Core`: [Project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#project-files)

Hence the reason why (emphasis mine):

> In this case, you would discover that your project **will not build** without the `.csproj` file...

Hth...

Comment: @MickyD from the above answer referenced as mentioned